# Notify when receive message XMPP + Smack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I'm just working with Smack and XMPP server and has problem when receive message from another user.

I have 2 user, when user1 send message to user2, user2 will be notified about new message.

In my app, I can see log about message received such as:

```
11-06 14:50:03.266 18753-19058/com.example.xmppdemo D/SMACK: RECV (0): <message id='05EW4-32' type='chat' to='off1@***' from='off2@***/Smack'><body>hhh</body></message>
```

**But I do not know how to handle this message to show notify for user2 ?**

Anyone know it ? Help me please

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try :**

```
chatListner = new PacketListener() 
        {
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) 
            {
                printLog("packet got");
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                printLog("packet subject" + message.getSubject());
                printLog("packet body" + message.getBody());
                printLog("packet id"+message.getPacketID());

            }
        }
```